# Implication inside set builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[ Edited]

Suppose a set S is defined by

S = { x | x belongs to A --> x belongs to B }

( i. e. S is the set of all x such that  if x belongs to A, then x belongs to B)

and that the sets A and B are (1) non empty (2) unequal (3) both different from the universal set .

The question I'm asking is : is it possible that

(1) S is identical to the null set? if so, in which case?

(2) S is identitcal to the universal set? if so, in which case?

Comment: Who chooses $A$ and $B$? In part (2), do you mean $S$ is identical to the universal set? What have you tried? :)

Comment: Sorry , my mistake . In (2) read : " S is identical to the universal set ? "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $P \implies Q$ in the equivalent form $\lnot P \vee Q$, we see that
$$
S = \{ x : x \in A \implies x \in B \} =  \{ x : x \notin A \vee x \in B \} = A^c \cup B
$$
Therefore, $S$ is never empty.

Moreover, when $B \supset A$, we have $S=U$.

Comment: Thanks! Took me some time to relate superset notation to the reverse inclusion, and finally to the conditional defining the set S. But that's ok ! Actually, In case A is included in B, then for all x, 'x belongs to A' implies 'x belongs to B', so any element x of U  meets the necessary and sufficient condition to belong to S.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to us to choose $A$ and $B$, so we can choose them such that the above conditions hold / not hold. So, let $U$ be the universe set that is under consideration. Now, picking:

1. $A \subset U, B = A^c$, will mean that $\forall x \in A, x \notin B$. Hence, there exists *no element* $x$ such that $x \in A \implies x \in B$. This answers question 1.
2. For part 2, set $A = B = U$. Now, $\forall x \in A, x \in B$, and $A = U$, hence $S = U$.

Comment: @ Siddharth Bhat Thanks for your answer.. Do you think the condition you state for (2) is the only possible one? I've edited my question  in order to obtain more " ordinary " cases as the one in which A=B=U ( if there is any, of course).